# SQL date format conversion to MMDDYYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What's the best way to convert the following statement to show the `MMDDYYYY` format such as `02022013` without slashes or hyphens...

```
CONVERT (CHAR(10), A.POKFRM, 112)
```

Comment: My first reaction would be: **don't**. Formatting data (not just date/times) is a responsibility of the view (be it an HTML page, report, PDF exporter, (G)UI or whatever). Although it *can* be done in SQL, it's not it's job to do that. Question yourself: do I want to implement this specific formatting in (what is typically) the tool that stores my data or in the tool that knows about my user, his/her preferences, locale, (possibly) timezone etc.?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could take a formatting that gives you elements in order but with `/` or `-` and then replace the `/` or `-` to get your desired result.

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT (CHAR(10), getdate(), 101),'/','')
```

Result:

```
02022015
```

Comment: that is the correct format but its showing the same date for all entries. there are multiple/different entries in the table. Thanks again...

Comment: @khan16 use your `DATE` field in place of `GETDATE()`

Comment: That's coz I used getdate() for the example, change getdate() to your columnname

Comment: something like this..if my column name is svcfrm for instance: REPLACE(CONVERT (CHAR(10),svcfrm(), 101),'/','')

Comment: remove the parens `REPLACE(CONVERT (CHAR(10),svcfrm, 101),'/','')`

Comment: I spoke too soon my man...for some reasons the output is still showing the same dates for all entries....

Comment: `REPLACE(CONVERT (CHAR(10),svcfrm, 101),'/','') ` is that your code piece?